# how to find 'manager' of a contact in an organisation using outlook api?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-restapi

In Outlook , there a handy feature - organization information, which let you see one's manager. Is there a way to find details of manager(name and email ID in particular) of a contact using outlook/graph api??
PS->Even after using scope-'contacts.read', I am unable to see name of manager.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL you are using?

With `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager` it works fine here in the graph explorer.

Any one of these scopes should be enough: User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All; Directory.Read.All; Directory.ReadWrite.All; Directory.AccessAsUser.All (according to the docs for [Get Manager](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_manager)).

Comment: I can see my own managers' detail. I am unable to get name of managers of other users using the API. It is asking access from admin account(which I don't have). Although I can see the hierarchy in 'organization information' in outlook app and office outlook website.

Comment: BTW thanks for help. Now, I am using my company's cloud gateway for the same and can get data from there.

Comment: The Directory.xyz scopes require admin approval. The reason that Outlook can use them, is because the Office 365 apps are trusted in Azure AD. If you want to use those scopes from an app that you develop, one of your AAD admins needs to grant it access.